# User Journey Map confusion regarding starting point and goals

Tags: journey-map

I'm taking some online coursework to improve some of my weaknesses regarding research.
I'm creating a User Journey Map for a case study and am a bit baffled by some context.

Hypothetically, let's say I'm designing an app that provides users with information regarding whatever airport they've arrived at in the world.

- The persona frustration consists of language barriers and difficulty hearing announcements, locating / deciphering public transit etc.
- The goal is to provide them with an easier way of learning about the airport, looking at potential schedules, transportation etc.

What I'm confused about is:

1. Should I be designing this UJM with the *prior/existing* workflow?

   - what they have to currently go through, or what workflow they would go through with my app (which doesn't exist yet)?

I'm unsure if I'm supposed to be speculating all the ways to address their problem in the new app or simply defining their current journey to realize all of the pain points, etc. as well as how they currently achieve their goal.

**Or** am I documenting their current journey and then introducing the app within one of the phases to address frustrations?

Given that this is coursework, there is certainly some speculation here which may be adding to the ambiguity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course as with everything in UX, the right answer is "it depends" ;-). Why are you creating the map? Is it to map out reality so you can understand the problem space, or is it to show the newer, proposed flow for your improved solution to the problem?

I have found it a worthy exercise to do both - map out the current, frustrating journey and note all the pain points and frustrations along the way. Then map your proposed new journey and flow and highlight how many steps are saved, or at least how the same steps are improved with the new journey.

I've done this before in real-world situations and it has proven very helpful in showing the value of a proposed solution to stakeholders before the work is fully undertaken:

[image: Current and Proposed journey maps]

Good luck!

Comment: Oooh. I like this solution a lot. I think this satiates my own pain points and goals ;)

Thanks for the response, very helpful!

Comment: +1, Both the "as-is" and the "to-be" states -- in their entirely -- need to be visible.